# Python try/except

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I'm trying a small program out of the Automate the Boring Stuff book.

I want to ensure that someone inputting a non-int variable will not crash the program. The code kicks out an error saying that the "break" command is not in the loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import random
print ('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input()
secretNumber=random.randint(1,20)
print('Well ' + name + ', I\'m thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

for guessesTaken in range(1,7):
    print()
    print ('Take a guess')
try:
    guess = int(input())

except ValueError:
    print ('I said guess a number not letters or words.')

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job! You guessed it.')
else:
    print('Nope the number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber)+' sorry.')
```

Comment: Post your code here!

Comment: More specifically, post a [mcve] of your code here.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I suspect the "else" command is not in the loop.

Comment: It's no good formatted like that in a comment.  Edit your post to include the code - see jonrsharpe's link above in the comments.

Comment: The code is in the link attached. Sorry the book says to provide a link like that when asking questions and not just post lots of code. I don't know the proper etiquette. Thank you.

Comment: indentation error. close as typo?

Comment: @FirstTogo look at a few other questions that actually have been answered. you should notice a thing or 2 about what is expected of the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is not correct. Notice that the `try` block and everything underneath it is no longer in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, remember to always post your code in here, thay way you will avoid the downvotes.

At looking at your code i could easily tell you a few things:

1) Indent this piece of code since it is actually out of the `for` loop.

```
try:
    guess = int(input())

except (ValueError, NameError):
    print ('I said guess a number not letters or words.')
    break

if guess < secretNumber:
    print('Your guess is too low.')
elif guess > secretNumber:
    print('Your guess is too high.')
else:
    break
```

2) You should make a break in the `except` block (like i did above) so it won't execute the next block of `if` statements or you will also get the exception for `NameError` because since the `guess` variable wasn't created the next `if` statement `if guess "<" secretNumber:` would throw an exception.

3) This code is kinda broken because if it throws an exception and guess isn't created, the last `if` statement out of the `for` loop would also throw an exception, so i recommend you to initialize that variable before the `for` statment like this: `guess = 0`.

Your final code should look like this:

```
import random
print ('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input()
secretNumber=random.randint(1,20)
print('Well ' + name + ', I\'m thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
guess = 0

for guessesTaken in range(1,7):
    print()
    print ('Take a guess')
    try:
        guess = int(input())

    except (ValueError, NameError):
        print ('I said guess a number not letters or words.')
        break

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job! You guessed it.')
elif guess == 0:
    None
else:
    print('Nope the number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber)+' sorry.')
```

There is still room for improvement but this will fulfill your request.

Have a good day =).